# Count unique user and show the result only

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

We have Group A and B and nested group in Group B.
John is member to Group A and is in Australia 1 OU.
Chris is member to Group B and is in Australia 2 OU.
May is member to Group A and B and is in Australia 1 OU.
Ken is member of Group A and is in China OU.

Australia 1 and Australia 2 are a subOU of Australia.

I need to find the unique user in both A and B group and need PowerShell to shown result as below.

```
OU                        User Count in A and B Group
Australia 1                             2
Australia 2                             1
Other                                   1
```

I am trying to export the COUNT but somehow the sum isn't correct. What should be change to get it right?

```
$Group2 = $groupA, $GroupB
$Group2 |
    ForEach-Object { $gm += Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$_" -Recursive } |
    Where-Object { $_.objectClass -ieq "User" } |
    Select-Object -Unique |
    Get-ADUser -Properties canonicalName |
    Select-Object @{Name='container';Expression={$_.canonicalname | Split-Path -Parent}} |
    Group-Object container |
    Select Count |
    Format-Table -Auto

$gm.Count + "," | Out-File $log -Append
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of what is in $Group2. Not real names, just an example of how $Group2 is structured. When you say COUNT is incorrect, what do you think it should be and what is it? I will try and do some testing in my test environment. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: As above. I edited the question.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Will setup my test environment and see what I can work out. Cheers.

Comment: Please do not remove relevant parts of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted can't possibly work, because your `ForEach-Object` loop appends to a variable without writing anything to the pipeline, so the entire pipeline after that initial loop doesn't do anything. At all.

Also, `$gm.Count + ","` should produce an error, because PowerShell would try to convert the string "," to an integer to match the type of the first operand. And fail. You'd need to cast the first operand to a string to make `+` work as a concatenation operator. But even then you wouldn't get the desired result, because `$gm` contains all group members irrespective of their OU.

To make your code work remove the `ForEach-Object` loop and the `$gm =`, and select both the name and the count of the grouped container names.

```
$Group2 |
    ForEach-Object { $gm += Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$_" -Recursive } |
    Where-Object { $_.objectClass -ieq "User" } |
    Select-Object -Unique |
    Get-ADUser -Properties canonicalName |
    Select-Object @{Name='container';Expression={$_.canonicalname | Split-Path -Parent}} |
    Group-Object container |
    Select Name, Count |
    Format-Table -Auto
```

If you want just the trailing part of the container name change the expression

```
$_.canonicalname | Split-Path -Parent
```

to

```
$_.canonicalname | Split-Path -Parent | Split-Path -Leaf
```

If you want the tabular output written to a file add

```
| Out-String | Out-File $log
```

after the `Format-Table` statement, or replace `Format-Table -Auto` with `Export-Csv $log -NoType` if you want the result as a CSV.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, if I apply Split-path -Leaf, if won't show the australia but the subOU. For example: \TIMHAINTZ\DC\Australia\Australia1\People\ if will just show People instead Australia1.

Comment: If you want the OU at the 5th level of hierarchy use `($_.canonicalname -split '\\')[4]` instead of `Split-Path`.

Comment: I tried. If using th code above, the count will be unique. I have to use split-path parent in order for the count to show unique.

Comment: My bad, the path uses forward slashes, so it should've been `($_.canonicalname -split '/')[4]`.

Comment: It worked. Now is a big issue, i have many groups and how can I combin all the result into one single cvs with neat format?

Comment: I am trying to use write-output but it seem doesn't work.
write-output ABC Company $group2

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have come up with. Hopefully this gets you to the answer. I have used some extra variables to break up your piping.

I have also added in the PowerShell I used to setup the OU, User and Group structure. I used Group1 and Group2 instead of GroupA and GroupB. That was an error on my part.

I created my users as inetOrgPerson so in where-object, I'm using that for -ieq. You will need to change that to User.

```
#Environment setup
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name Country -Path "DC=TIMHAINTZ,DC=COM"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name Australia -Path "OU=Country,DC=TIMHAINTZ,DC=COM"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name Australia1 -Path "OU=Australia,OU=Country,DC=TIMHAINTZ,DC=COM"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name Australia2 -Path "OU=Australia,OU=Country,DC=TIMHAINTZ,DC=COM"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name China -Path "OU=Country,DC=TIMHAINTZ,DC=COM"
New-ADUser John -Type iNetOrgPerson -Path "OU=Australia1,OU=Australia,OU=Country,DC=timhaintz,DC=com" 
New-ADUser Chris -Type iNetOrgPerson -Path "OU=Australia2,OU=Australia,OU=Country,DC=timhaintz,DC=com"
New-ADUser May -Type iNetOrgPerson -Path "OU=Australia1,OU=Australia,OU=Country,DC=timhaintz,DC=com"  
New-ADUser Ken -Type iNetOrgPerson -Path "OU=China,OU=Country,DC=timhaintz,DC=com"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name Groups -Path "DC=TIMHAINTZ,DC=COM" 
New-ADGroup -Name "Group1" -SamAccountName Group1 -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName "Group1" -Path "OU=Groups,DC=TimHaintz,DC=com"  
New-ADGroup -Name "Group2" -SamAccountName Group2 -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName "Group2" -Path "OU=Groups,DC=TimHaintz,DC=com"  
Add-ADGroupMember Group1 John  
Add-ADGroupMember Group2 Chris 
Add-ADGroupMember Group1 May  
Add-ADGroupMember Group2 May 
Add-ADGroupMember Group1 Ken

#Iteration through groups
$group2 = 'CN=Group1,OU=Groups,DC=timhaintz,DC=com','CN=Group2,OU=Groups,DC=timhaintz,DC=com'
$users = foreach($group in $group2)
     {
         Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -ieq "inetOrgPerson"}
     }
$uniqueusers = $Users | Select-Object -Unique
```

From here, you have all $users and $uniqueusers. If you do:

```
$users.count
$uniqueusers.count
```

You will see they have a different number.

You can then use the rest of your logic to get the counts and output as you would like.
For example:

```
$uniqueusers | `
get-aduser -Properties canonicalname | `
Select-Object @{Name='container';Expression={$_.canonicalname | split-path -parent}} |  `
Group-Object container | ` 
Select-Object @{Name='OU';Expression={($_.name).Split("\")[-1]}},Count | `
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Outputs the below:

```
OU         Count
--         -----
Australia1     2
China          1
Australia2     1
```

You can use $users and pipe that into get-aduser etc. also.

Hope this helps.

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Hi Tim, appreicate your time created an example.
I already have the result as above were the the same as yours. 
I'll like it to show Australia1  then count 2 instead showing timhaintz.com\Country\Australia\Australia1. And how to output as table format?

Comment: Will have a look in about 30 minutes to an hour. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer to just show Australia1 etc. I added in Format-Table -AutoSize. Please see @ansgarWiechers answer about outputting. I have also used the split method, Ansgar has used split-path -Parent | split-path -Leaf which is neater than using two calculated properties like I used. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Appreicate Tim. I tried using your code but the OU output is blank. In addition the count keep repeated twice.

Comment: Are you using $uniqueusers to pipe through? $users will keep on increasing each time you run the foreach loop. To reset the variable, you can run $users = $null. I’m replying on my mobile at the moment. When I’m near my computer again, will reply. If you run everything before group-object, are you getting the OU output?

Comment: On computer again. If you break each pipe down, are you getting the objects flowing through. For example, run $uniqueusers | get-aduser -Properties canonicalname. Are you getting objects? Then run $uniqueusers | get-aduser -Properties canonicalname | Select-Object @{Name='container';Expression={$_.canonicalname | split-path -parent}} are you still getting objects? Iterate through that and see where it stops pipping the objects through or the property names change. Testing on mine, OU is populated if run in the order I have in the answer.Thanks, Tim.

Comment: How to I check if mine if from iNetOrgPerson? And how do I switch if OU=Australia1,OU=Australia,OU=Country,DC=timhaintz,DC=com", I just want to show the second OU that is Australia only?

Comment: I guess the reason why the OU is empty could be because I put the wrong switch.  Where-Object { $_.objectClass -ieq "User" }. I need to find out the correct objectclass where the user reside?

Comment: If I would like to use write-out , what should I put to get the count to show?

Comment: Do you have all the other bits working now? I'm not sure where you are up to, is everything reporting correctly?

Comment: Where are you wanting to put write-output? From the write-output documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-5.1 "Sends the specified objects to the next command in the pipeline. If the command is the last command in the pipeline, the objects are displayed in the console."